# Help with rational functions word problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When looking at a rational function, Jamal and Angie have two different thoughts. Jamal says that the function is defined at $x = -3, x = -4$, and $x = 6$. Angie says that the function is undefined at those $x$ values. Describe a situation where Jamal is correct, and describe a situation where Angie is correct. Is it possible for a situation to exist that they are both correct?

My thoughts:
I don't understand what they mean when they ask "the function is DEFINED at $x= -3,-4, \& 6$. And how would a situation would be possible to be undefined and the function is defined.

Comment: is $\ln 0$ defined?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) = \frac 1x$. This function is not defined at $x=0$.  Now consider the function $f(x) = \frac1{x^2-1}$.  This function is not defined at $x=\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

A rational function $p(x)/q(x)$ is undefined at those $x$ for which $q(x) = 0$.
Otherwise it is defined.
The only "gray area" is when $p(x) = d(x) f(x)$ and $q(x) = d(x) g(x)$ for some polynomials $d, f, g$: then at points where $d(x) = 0$ but $g(x) \ne 0$, 
Angie can say $p(x)/q(x)$ is undefined but Jamal can say $p(x)/q(x) = f(x)/g(x)$  and $f(x)/g(x)$ is defined.